# SQL Server, how to query a string containing multiple apostrophes?

Tags: sql-server

There's a bug in my program that's replicating apostrophes in a string in our database. It's the string 'RAYNAUD'S SYNDROME' that has upwards of 32k apostrophes in there. What is the best way to write a SELECT query to call a string with that many apostrophes? All of the demonstrations I've seen on line for selecting a string with an apostrophe have only been to deal with a single apostrophe.

Comment: What is the purpose of the select statement? Are you just trying to find the rows that have the bad strings?

Comment: @hatchet, exactly, I'm trying to identify the bad strings so I can replace them with an update statement.

Comment: Preferably, what I'd like to do is:

SELECT * FROM (table name) WHERE (Column name) and then specify maybe with wildcards something that has several apostrophes in a row. I get the feeling that not all of the rows I want to call have the same amount of apostrophes, but all of them have an abnormally large amount of apostrophes.

Comment: Would something like `SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE myColumn LIKE 'RAYNAUD''S SYNDROME' AND LEN(myColumn) > 18` work?

Answer (score 0):

This will return all rows in YourTable where YourColumn contains at least one apostrophe. Replace 0 with whatever count of apostrophes you need to check for.

```
select *
from [YourTable]
where LEN([YourColumn]) - LEN(REPLACE([YourColumn], '''', '')) > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

To extract records that have many apostrophe's, you can write a query like this:

```
create table test (somedata varchar(100));
insert into test values ('''hello'' ''again''')

select * from test 
where len(somedata) - len(REPLACE(somedata, '''', '')) > 0
```

To update all those records, you could do

```
update test
set somedata = REPLACE(somedata, '''', '')
where len(somedata) - len(REPLACE(somedata, '''', '')) > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Two approaches:

This is if you are specifically looking for bad versions of the string you mentioned

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE myColumn LIKE 'RAYNAUD''S SYNDROME' AND LEN(myColumn) > 18
```

and the other is more general for finding rows with more than 2 single quotes (you could change it to look for some other threshold number)

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE LEN(REPLACE(myColumn,'''','') < LEN(myColumn) - 2
```

Comment: Thanks hatchet. I was able to pull results with this query:

SELECT * FROM PatDx WHERE Description LIKE 'RAYNAUD%' AND LEN(Description) > 18

(Sorry, new to StackOverflow, not sure how to format code, the markdown doesn't agree with me)

And am going to attempt a similar UPDATE statement with that WHERE clause.

Comment: Just be careful there are no side effects (that there are other OK strings that happen to have 'RAYNAUD' in them.